# Custom Post Type and Taxonomy Loop Output Is Wrong

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

I'm trying to loop through the various posts that fit within my custom taxonomy: "industries". The post type is custom (type: "member") and so I've been trying to build a loop that outputs the current taxonomy header and then the businesses that have that category assigned to them. Like so:

### Business Services:

Company A

### Construction Services:

Company B

Except with my current code it outputs all businesses under each heading. I'm sure the logic is just not quite right, but I am trying to figure out what I've done wrong and I can't see it.

My archive-members.php code:

```
  $categories = get_terms('industries', array(
    'hide_empty' => 1
  ));

  foreach($categories as $category) {

    $post_array = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'members', 'industries' => $category->name));
    setup_postdata($post_array);
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>

    <?php
      if(have_posts()):
        while(have_posts()):
          the_post();
    ?>

    <p> <?php the_title(); ?> </p>

    <?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  }
```

Comment: The example for [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) shows how it is used. You're currently not outputting any of those results, and are just running the main query loop over and over for each of your categories.

Comment: Oh! I'll have a read, thank you. If you'd like to do up a quick answer replacing my main loop code with the proper methods from the object returned by get_posts I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this, with WP Query. As @Milo pointed out, the issue is that the above code is running the main WP loop on each successive iteration and that loop isn't picking up on the custom query. Creating a loop from WP Query will yield the right results.

```
<?php 

$categories = get_terms('industries', array(
    'hide_empty' => 1
));

foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $category->name; ?></h1>
    <?php
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'members' ),
        'industries'          => $category->name,
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            ?>
            <p> <?php the_title(); ?> </p>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Actually, using my custom taxonomy name was working fine (otherwise the `$categories` array/object would just be empty. But as pointed out by @Milo above, I was using the main query loop without the affected results.

Comment: This does look like the right approach to The Loop, so if you want to amend this (and it tests alright) I'll mark it correct. But this is the query that is working for me: `$post_array = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'members', 'industries' => $category->name));`

Comment: Then maybe using `'tax_query' => array(
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'industries',
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $category->name,
     ),
    )` instead of `'category_name'          => $category->name,`

Comment: I tried your code and it works great. Thanks for the answer! I did make a minor edit as `'industries' => $category->name` works fine.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Are you sure? I haven't done that ever haha Shouldn't it be tax_query instead of only 'industries'? If it works for you then I'll approve your edit!

Comment: Yep. :) Registering the custom taxonomy in `functions.php` made it visible in this manner. I've already run and tested this code against what I had and it's working as intended!

Comment: Perfect, then, I approved it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50394/discussion-between-armadadrive-and-dgarceran).